# app intro images using viewpageindicator don't swipe smoothly

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swipe, viewpagerindicator

I am using ViewpagerIndicator library for sliding app intro images. 
The way I do it: 
1) Create 2 Fragments with background as the intro images. These images match the parents in width and height.
2) Create a fragment activity and pop these 2 fragments into the activity.

The problem:
Upon swiping horizontally, the fragments get swiped too slowly. I feel something is wrong with images occupying the whole view. But I am unable to figure out the problem.

Here is my FragmentActivity:

```
public class DemoActOne extends FragmentActivity{
    public DemoFragAdapter mAdapter;
    public ViewPager mPager;
    public PageIndicator mIndicator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.simple_lines);
        mAdapter = new DemoFragAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mIndicator = (LinePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
    }

}
```

Here is my DemoFragAdapter:

```
public class DemoFragAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private int mCount = 2;

    public DemoFragAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return DemoOne.newInstance();
        }
        else {
            return DemoTwo.newInstance();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCount;
    }

}
```

Here is DemoOne fragment - DemoTwo is same except for the relative layout background image I load.

```
public class DemoOne extends Fragment {
    private View mReturnView;
    public static DemoOne newInstance() {
        DemoOne fragment = new DemoOne();
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mReturnView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.demo_one, container, false);
        return mReturnView;
    }


}
```

Here is demo_one.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/demo1"
    android:clickable="false">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Why am I not able to swipe comfortably?

Edit: Image sizes are 1280 X 1920 - if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem might be solved if you 9 patch those images...
Here is the link where you can do that online :

[Android Asset Studio - 9 Patch Generator](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html)